# Excel: a matrix table with 1 and 0

Tags: excel, powerquery, data-analysis

If this is my data:

| Name | City Visited |
| --- | --- |
| Anna | LA |
| Leo | New York |
| Leo | LA |

how to create a table (preferably PIVOT table) like this in Excel:

|  | New York | LA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Anna | 0 | 1 |
| Leo | 1 | 1 |

So the result needs to be something like a matrix table where 1 means a person visited the city, and 0 means a person didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following using `POWER QUERY`

[image]

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Name", "City Visited"}, {{"Count", each _, type table [Name=text, City Visited=text]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each Table.AddIndexColumn([Count],"Index",1,1)),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Custom"}),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Custom", {"Name", "City Visited", "Index"}, {"Name", "City Visited", "Index"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Expanded Custom", List.Distinct(#"Expanded Custom"[#"City Visited"]), "City Visited", "Index", List.Count)
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

---

[image]

---

Or Using `PIVOTBY()`

[image]

---

```
=PIVOTBY(Table1[Name],Table1[City Visited],Table1[City Visited],COUNTA,0,0,,0)
```

---

Using `Pivot Table`

[image]

---

Comment: Thank you very much, but do you know how to maybe do it with pivot tables? Power query is not the best option for me right now.

Comment: @Ravena posted using `Power Query` , `PIVOTBY()` --> `Works with MS365 Beta` & using `Pivot Table`

Answer (score 1):

Just use a [Pivot Table](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576):

[image]

Take `name` field into rows and values section and `city` field into columns section. For easier reading deactivate subtotals and grandtotals and apply tabular view.

Answer (score 1):

Via PowerQuery, you can add a custom column for `1` then Pivot:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table4"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Name", type text}, {"City Visited", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each 1),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Added Custom", List.Distinct(#"Added Custom"[#"City Visited"]), "City Visited", "Custom", List.Sum)
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

Answer (score 0):

This works with excel functions only. Place these formulas in the defined cells:

F1: `=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(B2:B4))`

E2: `=UNIQUE(A2:A4)`

F2: `=IF(SUM(($A$2:$A$4=$E2)*($B$2:$B$4=F$1))>0,1,0)`

The formula in F2 has to be copied in the matrix range

Result:

[image]